# Mips recursion that I am stuck at

Tags: recursion, mips

Okay Im trying to do C(n, k) = C(n - 1, k - 1) + C(n - 1, k).

So far I have:

```
$a0 - n
$a1 - k
$v0 - C(n, k)

addi $sp, $sp, 8
sw $ra, 4($sp)
sw $s0, 0($sp)
addi $a0, $a0, -1
addi $a1, $a1, -1
lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $s0, 4($sp)
```

Now Im lost on what to do next please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If I look right, it's about the binomial coefficient. Yes, the first steps into MIPS can be kinda confusing, but practice is the key to get better. I don't know if you are in any course or anything. I wrote up something for you, here with the extra feature of getting the input values for n and k. In the end, it prints out the result of C(n, k).

```
.TEXT
    .GLOBL  __MAIN
__MAIN:
    LI      $V0, 4           // print1 asking you for number (n).
    LA      $A0, PRINT1
    SYSCALL
    LI      $V0,5           // do a syscall that reads an integer.
    SYSCALL
    MOVE    $T0, $V0

    LI      $V0, 4           // print2 asking you for number (k).
    LA      $A0, PRINT2
    SYSCALL
    LI      $V0,5           // do a syscall that reads an integer.
    SYSCALL
    MOVE    $A0, $T0
    MOVE    $A1, $V0
    JAL BINOMIALVAL

// this marks the end of procedure call. woo.

    MOVE    $T0, $V0

    LI      $V0, 4          // prints print3.
    LA      $A0, PRINT3
    SYSCALL

    MOVE    $A0, $T0
    LI      $V0,1           // this prints your c(n,k)
    SYSCALL

    LI      $V0,4           // this will print an eol. (end of line)
    LA      $A0, CR
    SYSCALL

    LI      $V0,10          // exit here.
    SYSCALL

 // will display the result and exit.

 BINOMIALVAL:
         SLT     $T0, $A0, $A1         // if n < k, then set t0 to 1.
         BNE     $T0, $ZERO, END1      // if t0 != 0, then branch to end1.
         BEQ     $A0, $A1, END2        // if n == k, then branch to end2
         BEQ     $A1, $ZERO, END2      // if n == 0, then branch to end2.

         SW      $FP, -4($SP)
         ADDI    $FP, $SP, 0
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, -12
         SW      $RA, 4 ($SP)
         SW      $A0, 0 ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, -4
         SW      $T1, ($SP)
         ADDI    $A0, $A0, -1
         JAL     BINOMIALVAL

         MOVE    $T1, $V0
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, -4
         SW      $A1, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, -4
         SW      $RA, ($SP) 

         ADDI    $A1, $A1, -1

         JAL     BINOMIALVAL

         ADD     $V0, $T1, $V0

         LW      $RA, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, 4

         LW      $A1, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, 4

         LW      $T1, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, 4

         LW      $A0, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, 4
         LW      $RA, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, 4
         LW      $FP, ($SP)
         ADDI    $SP, $SP, 4
         J       COMPLETE

END1:   MOVE    $V0, $ZERO         
        J       COMPLETE

END2:   ADDI    $V0, $ZERO, 1

COMPLETE:    JR      $RA        // return to normal routine.

.DATA

PRINT1:   .asciiz "Enter your value for n "

PRINT2:   .asciiz "Enter your value for k "
PRINT3:   .asciiz "Value of c(n,k) = "
CR:     .asciiz "\n"
```